# How to use Split function in Hive shell terminal

Tags: sql, shell, hive

Below statement works completely fine in SQL Workbench(hive):

```sql
select split(split('word1;with;some;meaning,;word2,;word3,;', ',;')[0],';')[0];
```

The above statement yields the output: `word1`

Step 1:

```
select split('word1;with;some;meaning,;word2,;word3,;', ',;')[0];
output 1: `word1;with;some;meaning`
```

step 2:

```
select split(split('word1;with;some;meaning,;word2,;word3,;', ',;')[0],';')[0];

output 2: `word1`
```

If I try the above in hive terminal I'm getting below error:
[hive terminal error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8zQC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I found this solution

```sql
select split(split(word_list,',\073')[0],'\073')[1];

'\073' is equivalent to ';'.
```

This serves my purpose. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

You need to shield semicolon `;` with `\\` because semicolon terminates string in hive CLI:

```
hive> select split(split('word1\\;with\\;some\\;meaning,\\;word2,\\;word3,\\;', ',\\;')[0],'\\;')[0];
OK
word1
Time taken: 0.276 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Shielded it works fine. And SQL workbench probably does this work for you.

Step1 fixed:

```
 hive> select split('word1\\;with\\;some\\;meaning,\\;word2,\\;word3,\\;', '[,\\;]')[0];
OK
word1
```

here `'[,\\;]'` - means `, or ;` as a delimiter

Comment: I cannot change the input string @leftjoin

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in the first token that is terminated by `;` then this could help

```
select regexp_extract("word1;with;some;meaning,;word2,;","(.*?);(.*)",1)
```

It works in Hue but not tested on CLI